# What's difference between np.zeros(img) and np.copy(img)*0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the difference between these three:

`np.zeros(img)`, `np.zeros_like(img)`, and `np.copy(img)*0`?

When should I use each of them?

Comment: I read the doc, but didn;t get the difference

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add what exactly you don't get, out of what the documentation states?

Comment: zeros() and zeros_like() both states to return array with zeros of same shape and type as provided, but what they do different?

Comment: They **take different inputs**

Comment: Improve punctuation and syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zeros` is the basic operation, creating an array with a given shape and dtype:

```
In [313]: arr = np.zeros((3,4),int)
In [314]: arr
Out[314]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`zeros_like` is an alternative input to `zeros`, where you provide an array, and it copies its shape and dtype (but not values):

```
In [315]: bar = np.zeros_like(arr)
In [316]: bar
Out[316]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`copy*0` also works, but generally I wouldn't recommend it.  I did use `N2 *=0` recently in while testing some code to reset an array.

```
In [317]: car = arr.copy()*0
In [318]: car
Out[318]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot of the python codes]

Despite they can reach a similar effect of creating a zero NumPy array of the shape you intended. Their performances are significantly different.

As shown in the screenshot below, `np.zeros_like(x)` is slightly slower than `np.zeros(x.shape)` while `np.copy(x)*0` is the slowest of all.

For example, if you increase the array size, you can really see the difference here:

[image]